# "No input file specified" Laravel Homestead

Tags: laravel, homestead

I've looked through the existing answers for similar questions, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

Navigating to `http://fresh.app:8000/` returns `no input file specified`. My local and virtual environments do sync up though (e.g. creating a file on in my virtual machine creates the corresponding file on my local machine).

`vagrant up`, `vagrant ssh` work and do not produce any errors.

My .env file has `APP_URL=fresh.app`

My `.homestead/Homestead.yaml` file:

```
ip: "127.0.0.1"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: fresh.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/fresh/public

databases:
    - homestead
    - fresh

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

in `/etc/hosts`, on my local machine I have:

```
127.0.0.1 fresh.app
```

On my virtual machine, in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/fresh.app`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name fresh.app;
    root "/home/vagrant/Code/fresh/public";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an index.php in your `public` folder?

Comment: Yes. The `fresh` folder contains all the files generated by `laravel new fresh`, which includes the index.php file in `public/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
folders:
    - map: /Code
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: fresh.app
     to: /home/vagrant/Code/public
```

I suspect that your core laravel installation is in /Code, therefore the above should correct your issue. Unless, your core installation is in /Code/fresh.

Another possible reason may be that the /Code path is not correct. You can verify by going into the project directory and getting the full path. If you're in linux, you can do:

```
pwd
```

That will specify the full path of it, and then you could update the

```
folders:
   - map: /the/full/path/to/the/core
```

After this, you run vagrant reload --provision

Let me know if it's still not working!

Comment: Thanks! `vagrant reload --provision` / restarting nginx seem to have fixed it.